# Import Fiddler certicicate

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, fiddler, powerbi

Im trying to get Odata service in Power Bi and i always get this error

```
  OData: Request failed: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

But when I do run the Fiddler and I add its certificate ,everything works perfect.
and when I close the Fiddler I get the same old error. How should I solve it, should I add this certificate to the IIS in case yes how!.

I added the Fiddler and the service link to the Trusted Root. But it did not work. 
always after closing Fiddler the connection is gone.

Comment: Are you able to access the OData service using a browser without security errors? I know Fiddler has an option to ignore certificate errod somewhere.

Comment: @kiewic actually yes but insecure connection becuase it is HTTPS and the certificate is not available